# Can hidden services be de-anonymized with little or considerable control of relay nodes and /or by network monitoring?

Tags: deanonymization

There are multiple papers detailing the de-anonymization approaches. But what i have observed is that (1) 100% de-anonymization may not be possible  (2) Even if its possible, one need to control lot many relays (guards, middle, exit, etc.) (3) Theoretically its may be proved but practically not possible.

At the same time LEAs are busting the sites now and then. How?

Is it possible to crack the sites by network flow monitoring?

Comment: A few of the cases I have heard about have been through attacks against the software that the service runs, not against the Tor network itself. For example see: https://riseup.net/en/security/network-security/tor/onionservices-best-practices#leaking-the-real-server

Comment: thanks!! @Steve